# How to position an ImageView in the same place in different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

I been working on a simple android app that calculates a person's Body Mass Index, I have all the features working but positioning the arrow in the right place in the color bar corresponding to the user's screen size is what Im stuck on. I have it working by setting the X and Y values of the arrow ImageView but obviously the place of the arrow changes when i test my application in different screen sizes even though im coverting a dp value to pixels. How can I position the arrow ImageView so that it stays the same in different screen sizes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="coding.guillermo.bmiapp.MainActivity2"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2"
android:clickable="false"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BMI"
    android:id="@+id/bmiText"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="21.24"
    android:id="@+id/bmiResult"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bmiText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bmiCategory"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="Normal weight"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bmiResult"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save result"
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/toolBarColor"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BMI Log"
    android:id="@+id/trackerButton2"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/toolBarColor"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/saveButton" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/bmibar"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bmiCategory" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Underweight &lt;18.50 "
    android:id="@+id/underweightText"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Normal 18.5 - 24.99"
    android:id="@+id/normalText"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/underweightText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/underweightText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Overweight >=25.00"
    android:id="@+id/overweightText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/normalText"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/normalText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Obese >=30.00"
    android:id="@+id/obeseText"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/overweightText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/overweightText" />
```

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView resultText,bmiLabel,underWeightText,normalText,overweightText,obeseText;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
Button saveButton,trackerButton;
Result result;
EditText userName;
DBhandler dbHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    // TextViews
    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiResult);
    bmiLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiCategory);
    underWeightText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.underweightText);
    normalText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.normalText);
    overweightText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.overweightText);
    obeseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.obeseText);
    // Button
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    trackerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trackerButton2);
    // Getting User object from the previous activity
    result = (Result) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("result");
    // Database
    dbHandler = new DBhandler(this);

    // Displaying the arrow in the corresponding place
    ImageView arrow = new ImageView(this);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
    arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow2);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

   // the display of the arrow is different when tested in device's with different screen sizes
    int dpValue = 0;
    int dpValue2 = 166;
    float d = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int margin = (int)(dpValue * d);
    int margin2 = (int) (dpValue2 * d);

    arrow.setX(margin);
    arrow.setY(margin2);
    rl.addView(arrow);

    // BMI diplay
    resultText.setText(Double.toString(result.getBMI()));
    bmiLabel.setText(result.getBmiCategory());
    // BMI category bold display
    bmiCategoryBold(result.getBMI());

    // Saving result to internal storage for later retrieval
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = (LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity2.this)).inflate(R.layout.alert_content,null);
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this);
            alertBuilder.setView(view);
            userName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            result.setDate(date);
            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            result.setName(userName.getText().toString());
            // adding result to the SQLite database
            dbHandler.addResult(result);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
            Button nButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            nButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolBarColor));
            nButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    });

    trackerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


public void bmiCategoryBold(double bmi){
    if(bmi < 18.50){
        underWeightText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }
    else if(bmi <= 24.99){
        normalText.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    }
    else if(bmi<=29.99){
        overweightText.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    }
    else{
        obeseText.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
    }
}

}
```

The first pic is the app running on 1080 pixels by 1920 pixels screen and the second is a 1440 pixels by 2560 pixels screen

[first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOw2Z.png)

[second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAUoK.png)

Comment: Check [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), official guide for the designing layouts for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Linearlayout as subparent of childview,use its orientation and gravity attribute you can easily get the design in more optimize way and suitable for everyscreen size.
here i have used RelativeLayout as Parent and LinearLayout as sub-parent of childview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BMI"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiResult"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="21.24"
                android:textSize="30dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bmiCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Normal weight"
                android:textSize="25dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/underweightText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Underweight &lt;18.50 "
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/normalText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Normal 18.5 - 24.99"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overweightText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Overweight >=25.00"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/obeseText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Obese >=30.00"
                android:textSize="22sp" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/trackerButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                    android:text="BMI Log"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
                        android:text="Save result"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try to avoid too much margin top and bottom.